# Rails call specific action on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

I have a model like this, for example:

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_reader :interests, :last_list_name, :type

  def initialize()
    @interests = 'fishing'
    @last_list_name = 'last_list'
  end

  def purple_contact
    @type = 'purple'
  end
end
```

Then, in my controller, I want to create different "types" of `Contact` models from a csv file based on whether or not they have a certain value as an attribute.

For example:

I know I can call `Contact.new` in my controller and create a `Contact` without a problem. How would I instead call something like `Purple_Contact.new`? I want everything in my initialize method to happen, but I want certain contacts to also have a `type` of `purple`.

So `Contact.new` would produce a contact with a `nil` value for `type`, but a "Purple Contact" would create a contact with a `purple` value for `type` as well as `fishing` for `interests`.

Comment: Why not just have a type of contact in the database then you can just assign the type when you do Contact.New(type)?

Comment: Basically every contact is going to have the same attributes, just the values will change based on what is seen in a csv file. I suppose I could create 15 different contact models, but it seemed cleaner to create one contact model with 15 different "types".

Comment: It sounds like you just want to create subclasses of `Contact`. Am I missing something more to this question?

Comment: No - You're correct. I want to create subclasses of Contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inheritance.

```
class PurpleContact < Contact
  def initialize
    super
    @type = 'purple'
  end
end
```

Comment: Using this method it seems like the only attribute that is getting defined is `type`. All of the values in my original `Contact` initialize method do not get assigned - Thoughts on how I can pull that in without writing `super(attribute)` over and over?

Comment: `super` invokes parent initialize method, so values in your original `Contact` initialize get assigned

Comment: valid - I was just making a simple mistake. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

`Purple_Contact.new` would be a different class from `Contact`, so it wouldn't work this way, per se.

What you could do is:

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_reader :interests, :last_list_name, :type

  def initialize()
    @interests = 'fishing'
    @last_list_name = 'last_last'
  end

  def self.purple(new_args = {})
    new_args[type] = 'purple'
    self.new(*new_args)
  end
end
```

This would let you do something like:

```
Contact.purple(initialization_hash)
```

which would return a new instance of Contact with @type set to purple.